# Simple HTML5 video playlist on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, html5-video

I have an old, first generation iPad that is almost useless and i'd like to transform it into a video player. I'm strugling to make a simple HTML5 video playlist page that i can load in Safari and have it play continuously. While it has no problems playing my MP4 video files individually, i cannot find a way to convince him to load and play the next video automatically.

To give a little bit more details, i want to have this iPad in the same local network with a NAS/webserver where my video files and this HTML file reside. The HTML file is `index.html` located at `http://192.168.86.11/internal/` and all my video files are numbered files, in the same folder. The iPad will get the content through WiFi, since it doesn't have anything else.

I provide the source code at the end. In order to debug it a little, i've placed a DIV that i update with various texts. For starter, i just want to have 2 video files play in a loop, `441.mp4` and `1127.mp4`. The first video plays fine (provided i start it manually), but the second one doesn't, no matter what i try. The order of events is the following:

- i load the HTML page in Safari; the debug shows me `loaded, video loaded` and the video player shows me the play button, waiting to press it;
- i press the play button; the `can play` text gets added to the debug and the video starts playing;
- the video finishes; the following gets added to the debug text: `finished, loading http://192.168.86.11/internal/1127.mp4, video loaded`, however the next video does not start.

So, anyway, is there such thing even possible or am i chasing unicorns ? It's not very clear to me (after searching alot on the internet) whether this is actually possible or not (i've seen various discussions about video autoload/autoplay not working on mobile devices, especially Apple's; but after all, i do actually start the playing manually, on the first video, so i woulnd't place this in the 'autoplay' problem bucket).

And if it is possible, could anyone shed some light on what i'm not doing (right) here ?

Some more informations:

1. the iPad model is A1219 (on the back cover), MB292LL (in the software), running iOS 5.1.1 (9B206) ... and this is the highest version i can have, it doesn't update to anything newer;
2. the iPad has been resetted to factory defaults, so it has no possible flaws due to bad software installations / uninstallations / misconfigurations;
3. all video files (and especially these 2) work perfectly alone, they have been converted with ffmpeg with a custom command especially to make them work with this iPad; individually (and manually), they play fine;
4. any idea is welcomed, i could use any web library / solution, however i do prefer simpler solutions;
5. i've read in another stackoverflow post that some Apple mobile products don't want to autoplay files larger than 3 MB; while this would be a problem for me, these 2 test files only have 1 MB, so this shouldn't be a problem here;
6. everything works well and as expected on something else, like Android 6 + Chrome 87 (i don't even need to press anything, the autoplay actually works from start).

Thank you very much !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
</head>
<body style="background: #000; margin: 0; position: relative;">
    <div id="hDebug" style="color: #FFF; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 999;">loaded</div>
    
    <video autoplay muted playsinline controls style="width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0;" id="hVideo">
        <source src="" type="video/mp4" id="hVideoFile">
        nope
    </video>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        var arrPlaylist = [441, 1127];
        var nCursor = 0;
        var hVideo = document.getElementById('hVideo');
        var hVideoFile = document.getElementById('hVideoFile');
        var hDebug = document.getElementById('hDebug');
        
        function VideoEnded()
        {
            hDebug.innerHTML = hDebug.innerHTML + ', finished';
            
            nCursor++;
            if (nCursor >= arrPlaylist.length) nCursor=0;
            
            hVideoFile.src = 'http://192.168.86.11/internal/' + arrPlaylist[nCursor] + '.mp4';
            
            hDebug.innerHTML = hDebug.innerHTML + ', loading http://192.168.86.11/internal/' + arrPlaylist[nCursor] + '.mp4';
            
            hVideo.load();
        }
        
        function AutoPlay()
        {
            hDebug.innerHTML = hDebug.innerHTML + ', video loaded';
            
            hVideo.play();
        }
        
        function CanPlay()
        {
            hDebug.innerHTML = hDebug.innerHTML + ', can play';
            
            hVideo.play();
        }
        
        // load the first file
        hVideo.addEventListener('ended', VideoEnded);
        hVideo.addEventListener('loadstart', AutoPlay);
        hVideo.addEventListener('canplaythrough', CanPlay);
        
        hVideoFile.src = 'http://192.168.86.11/internal/' + arrPlaylist[nCursor] + '.mp4';
        hVideo.load();
        
        // bottom align the player
        var hBody = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        hBody.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it needs more than HTML5 since HTML is only a markup language and can't do loops !

you can do this using for loop on javascript.

this function could be helpful for playing the next video

http://thenewcode.com/909/Create-An-Automatic-HTML5-Video-Playlist

peace!

Comment: Hello :) I have found that article in my searches, however it doesn't help. I never said i want a "pure HTML" solution, if you look in my source code you'll see there's more Javascript than HTML. That article does exactly what i'm doing - changing the `src` of the `source` tag, then calling `.load()` and `.play()` on the `video` tag. However, in my case it's not enough and i suspect it's got something to do with this iPad or Apple products in general (since this works on Android / Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

When you load the 2nd video into source, the player has state "ended". I think you need to send a 'hVideo.play();' to get it started again.